# Is there some limit on a size of a file when causing a download with PHP?

Tags: php, download, filesize

Trying to force-download file with PHP using usual:

```
header("Content-type: $type" );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
```

And it does successfully for files somewhere below 32 mb. For bigger ones it just returns zeroed file.

Obviously there's some kind of limit, but what sets it? Using Apache 2.2.11 and PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: PHP has no such limit. This should be asked on serverfault as it's related to your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually stumbled on this post: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/.

```
function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 /*
 This function takes a path to a file to output ($file), 
 the filename that the browser will see ($name) and 
 the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).

 If you want to do something on download abort/finish,
 register_shutdown_function('function_name');
 */
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 /* Figure out the MIME type (if not specified) */
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
    "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 /* The three lines below basically make the 
    download non-cacheable */
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // is also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else die('Error - can not open file.');

die();
}   

/*********************************************
            Example of use
**********************************************/

/* 
Make sure script execution doesn't time out.
Set maximum execution time in seconds (0 means no limit).
*/
set_time_limit(0);  
$file_path='that_one_file.txt';
output_file($file_path, 'some file.txt', 'text/plain');
```

Adding all the headers recommended there and also using:

```
 ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
```

before any output - has helped. No more limitations observable. Files download completely even huge ones.

Comment: Using `@` error suppression is inadvisable as it is slow and can lead to debugging nightmares.

Comment: #giveThisMan_a_bells! Thanks @Jayarjo, this solved it for me!

Comment: adding `ob_end_clean();` to my current script (before the headers) did the trick for me. Now I can download big files without them saying "0 bytes"

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're loading the entire file into RAM before sending it down to the recipient.  You'll want to look into PHP Streams to be able to send the full file contents without having to read it all into RAM first: http://php.net/streams

Comment: I'm using fopen, fread($fh, $chunksize), fclose functions. Are not they safe for such cases?

Comment: The easiest form is to use `readfile` http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: That's a good point deceze; I'm accustomed to piping data from a database or other source, so I fall back to streams when there's a simpler solution available.

Comment: jayarjo, it depends on what you're doing with it after you fread() it.    If you're just doing `while (!feof($fp)) { echo fread($fp, 1024); }` then this is probably fine (assuming output buffering is disabled), but if you're concatenating it to another string, you'll still run out of memory eventually.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was doing. Glad to know now that it is right, since I was doing it first time :)

Answer (score 1):

also may need to `set_time_limit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the php.ini you will see the setting.

I can't remember the option name off the top of my head, but I will look inside my php.ini now and try and find it.

Just remove it and it will work.

## Added

Okay, someone please correct me if I am wrong, but is it

> memory_limit

Comment: What? PHP doesn't have a "max download" setting of any type. Please take the time to at least research your answer so you can actually _provide one_.

Comment: I think the problem is because he is generating the file himself, hence the memory_limit above. Please correct me if I am wrong as I want to know this also.

Comment: There's not enough information present to determine that. memory_limit has to do with how much memory the script can use. This would only come into play if you attempted to read the entire file into memory, or enough of it to exceed the memory_limit. Sending headers doesn't do this.

Comment: Thats what I would infer anyway. Maybe I am wrong, hopefully the OP can clarify. And of course PHP doesn't have this setting, because apache is providing the file for download, but if PHP is generating it, you will potentially hit problems.

Comment: Regardless, memory_limit does not explicitly limit file download size.

Comment: I have one of my own scripts which creates a file. Is memory_limit an issue here. Its basically joining lots of files together.

Comment: I think there's more than enough information to reach this conclusion. ~32Mb is a fairly common memory limit for PHP and as Laykes says, PHP is generating the file after all.

Comment: @Oli: Laykes can't possibly know that, he's not the questioner here.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. Actually my memory_limit is set to 128 mb. What I do is read file by 1mb chunks and instantly echoing it and flushing the buffer (I just thought that's how the logic should go for big files). And I'm hitting that problem I described above.

Comment: I guess it was an issue of headers, but after I fixed it, another issue rose it's head - PHP framework was buffering the output. So your advice was also useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 GB limit build in Apache, even if u'll try to download a file from he root directory, completely avoiding php.

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever to debug.  I thought it might be the proxy behind CloudFlare, Header Missing.  Turned out the file I was streaming was hitting the memory limit.

I did

```
            ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```